# Responsive img in a jquery array

Tags: jquery, css, arrays, responsive

I found an image array created with jquery. I'm trying to get the imgs in the array to be responsive. The ultimate goal is to have them play nice with the masonry script which is why I have the generic grid classes that masonry uses. I've gotten it to work with width alone and height alone, but never together. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, and I haven't been able to locate a solid answer. If I need to go ahead and include the masonry script and code samples I can.

I'm not that great with jquery or java, so any help would be appreciated.

taylorbingham.com/ site where the script is running along with masonry. Image won't resize.

Original Script that I found for creating the cycle.
http://jsfiddle.net/Kz6Gk/353/

My modifications/code
https://jsfiddle.net/taylovision/gmxw6pbL/

```
.grid {
  background: #DDD;
}

.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.grid-sizer,
.grid-item {
  width: 25%;
}

.grid-item {
  float: left;
}

.grid-item img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.slideshow-block {
  width: 100%;
  background: #111;
}

a.link {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  z-index: 10;
}

a.link:hover {
  display: block;
}

.slides {
  width: inherit;
  z-index: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.slides.active {
  width: inherit;
  visibility: visible;
}

.slides.active img {
  width: inherit;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: http://taylorbingham.com/ site where the script is running along with masonry. Image won't resize.

Comment: Your problem seems to be jQuery cycle uses hard-coded values and doesn't update when its parent changes its size. It's not responsive. Use [Cycle 2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/).

Comment: Will this allow for the pause on hover state? I'm reading up on it now.

Comment: Found it. Going to test and will mark the answer in a moment.

Comment: Well, you'll need to define it, if it's not provided out of the box, by starting/playing the cycle plugin on a `.hover()` function. But it's way easier than trying to fix hard-coded responsiveness inside Cycle, IMHO. Edit: Which answer? :)

Comment: The Cycle 2. Right now I'm trying to get it to play nice with masonry. The other objects appear behind it.

Comment: taylorbingham.com


The issue now is that it won't sit in the grid on load, but it's fine once you resize. This is using cycle2. It's weird. Trying to figure it out.

Comment: Seems to work properly. Add `.cycle-slideshow img {position:absolute}` to your CSS to overlap the cycles until cycle plugins inits. After that, it will get overridden by inline styles added by the plugin on elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Blockquote
>   Your problem seems to be jQuery cycle uses hard-coded values and doesn't update when its parent changes its size. It's not responsive. Use Cycle 2. – Andrei Gheorghiu

[Cycle 2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/) resolved the issue.

Following code had to be included to resolve:

`<div class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-fx="none" data-cycle-auto-height="calc" data-cycle-pause-on-hover="true" data-cycle-speed="0.5s">`

This replaced .slideshow-block. Without the s declared in speed, it would not load properly with masonry.

Big thank you to Andrei

Comment: Mike Alsup rocks! :)